# Is demultiplexer universal gate?

Tags: digital-logic

I want to prove that demultiplexer is universal gate.
Can we build any logic gates using demultiplexer?
Can we build AND, NOT, OR gate?

Comment: Seems overly complex way to put it. NAND is the universal gate, and ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes. This is how you get the NOR function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUpCxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And if you can get NOR or NAND you can get any other gate. Though, since it takes two deMUXes to get a NOR, I don't know if it strictly is universal.

Comment: Got me! April Fool's to you, too!

Comment: In formal logic, you can't simply tie an input to 1 -- that's a function. This answer is adequate for someone building circuits, but doesn't match the textbook definition of "universal"

Comment: @trentcl I have never seen the term "universal gate" in a formal context. Admittedly, I was going to answer *no* because, as you pointed out, the A input is not negated. But, from a practical point of view, you can infact obtain any gate out of a combination of deMUXes.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, the demultiplexer is **not universal** ([functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness)) because it is *falsity-preserving* -- that is, if you set all the inputs to 0, you can't get a 1 out of any combination of demuxes.

(Note that a demux actually calculates two functions, and would therefore be considered two "gates" in abstract logic: the AND gate and a does-not-imply gate. Both these gates have the falsity-preserving characteristic, so the set containing both of them is not universal either.)

You can make a universal set by including the constant 1 -- this is easy to do in real electronics, where you may just tie an input to +Vcc. In other words, the set consisting of {AND, does-not-imply, 1} is universal.